# Any sample of openMap mraid or ormma API call

Tags: google-maps, mobile, maps, openmap

I'm looking to use the ormma or mraid api from the iab to display a map within the Ad unit.

I'm looking for a simple example of how to use the openMap() method that takes a POI.

I've tried a few experiments, but nothing seems to work at least in the mraid web tester.

Anyone know how to use this interface?

Thanks...

Answer (score 0):

test this section of code:

```
<a href=\"\" onclick=\"Ormma.openMap('http://maps.google.ru/maps?f=q&source=s_q&hl=ru&geocode=&q=%D1%80%D0%B5%D1%81%D0%BF%D1%83%D0%B1%D0%BB%D0%B8%D0%BA%D0%B0+%D0%9C%D0%B0%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%B9+%D0%AD%D0%BB,+%D0%99%D0%BE%D1%88%D0%BA%D0%B0%D1%80-%D0%9E%D0%BB%D0%B0&aq=0&sll=55.178868,49.658203&sspn=25.499525,80.683594&ie=UTF8&hq=&hnear=%D0%B3%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B4+%D0%99%D0%BE%D1%88%D0%BA%D0%B0%D1%80-%D0%9E%D0%BB%D0%B0,+%D1%80%D0%B5%D1%81%D0%BF%D1%83%D0%B1%D0%BB%D0%B8%D0%BA%D0%B0+%D0%9C%D0%B0%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%B9+%D0%AD%D0%BB&ll=56.642637,47.891464&spn=0.19029,0.630341&t=k&z=11&iwloc=A', true); return false;\">OPEN MAP</a>
```

I also leave the link where you can find the property siginificado each map, and add it to the URL

[Google Map Parameters Link](http://mapki.com/wiki/Google_Map_Parameters)

I hope you work

Comment: Thanks.  I'll try that.  Appreciate the response.